# Передача переменной в другую активити

Tags: android, java

Пишу приложение под android на джаве. Появилось нужда передать наименование выбранного файла в другой активити. Но проблема в том, что активити, в который надо передать переменную уже создан и через Intent сделать не получится. Т.к. если вызову startActivity, то все текстовые поля в этом активити сотрутся. Подскажите пожалуйста как сделать в этой ситуации?

**UPD:**
В общем есть активити1, там заполняются текстовые поля и можно добавить файл. При нажатии на "добавить файл" открывается активити2 с выбором файла. И вот после выбора файла мне нужно путь к этому файлу доставить в активити1 без потери уже введённых пользователем там текстовых полей.

Comment: в смысле создан ? нельзя редактировать код ?

Comment: Ну чтобы передать через Intent нужно выполнить функцию startActivity. А мне этого нельзя делать, т.к. в том активити заполнены поля текстовые, и если выполнять startActivity - всё сотрётся

Comment: показывааться может только одна actiity и  если вы передаете данные в другую то эта разрушается(помещается в стек) опишите лучше задачу, мне кажется мы друг друга не понимаем

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте метод [`startActivityForResult`](http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/68-urok-29-vyzyvaem-activity-i-poluchaem-rezultat-metod-startactivityforresult)

Comment: Спасибо, сейчас попробую